# Change Position Three.js / webgl vertex shader

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, particle-system

Hi I made a particle system, with three.js it uses normal JavaScript loops to change particle positions, but this is slow.

Because of this I have started to learn how to transfer this to the GPU via shader.

I have a problem, I cannot get the positions to change, each point stays at the same position.

```
var vertexShader = [
        'void main() {',
        '    vec3 newPosition = position.xyz;',
        '    newPosition.y += 10.0;',
        '    gl_PointSize = 1.00;',
        '    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( newPosition, 1.0 );',
        '}',
    ].join('\n');
```

why does

```
'    newPosition.y += 10.0;',
```

not change the particle positions?

Do I need some kind of time variable, I notice people seems to have these?
Thanks.

Comment: What is `position`? a uniform?

Comment: I don't have a clue, I'm using it like this:  _this.geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( _this.particleVertices, 3 ));

Comment: Ok, So I've just been reading, position is an attribute not a uniform, am i right in thinking uniforms get updated from the main program but attributes do not?

Comment: Now I see why people use a time variable, the uniform is updated, with each render loop, this value can be applied to the attributes, now my particles are moving, thanks Austin.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out, position is an Attribute, I need to pass a uniform to the Shader, this can be used to increment the position Attribute.

Vertex shader:

```
var vertexShader = [
        'uniform float time;',
        'void main() {',
        '   vec3 newPos = position;',
        '   newPos.x += time;',
        '   gl_PointSize = 1.00;',
        '   gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( newPos, 1.0 );',
        '}',
    ].join('\n');
```